# What is role of <service-name>SoapBindingImpl.java file

Tags: java, wsdl2java, axis

When we use `-s` option while generating stubs using `wsdl2java`(apache axis) tool it generates `<service-name>SoapBindingImpl.java` file.

This file contains all the method definition.

What is use of this file?

When exactly we need to edit the functions of this file?

If we just want to use the service do we even need this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is needed but not with stub its needed with skeleton. This is needed to call the impl class of al the API. if you just want to call the service, you dont need it. Because stub doesn't care about implementation. Its independent of that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. One more doubt ..For client side is there any requirement of option -server-side(-s) while generating the stub by wsdl2java tool. Because looks like we don't need Impl.java and *.wsdd files if we just want to use the exposed service.

Comment: nope....you are absolutely correct, there are no need of impl.java and  *.wsdd to invoke the exposed service.